# Custom WordPress Dashboard for Specific user role

Tags: wp-admin, dashboard

I want to customize dashboard or 1st page when user login into admin panel. This will be for Author/editor where he/she will only see some tabs/button of the pages and posts, by click them he/she can land on the page/post edit page. ;

I am pretty sure that "index.php" file will be edit under "wp-admin" folder but I just need some step by step guideline on this.

2nd thing I want Publish/update button to be shown below the content editor while hiding the right sidebar. I have tried it but couldn't find a clue. So any hep would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic implementation:

1. Create a page for the frontend (and optionally a template).
2. Then add the following code to your `functions.php`:

---

```
function login_redirect_capability() {
      if ( current_user_can('author') || current_user_can('editor')  ){
          return 'url-of your custom page';
      }
    }
add_filter('login_redirect', 'login_redirect_capability');
```

This will redirect them to the page you created. If you want to recode the dashboard as in the Wordpress admin backend, you can look at the [code in this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/dashboard/developers/) to see how it's done. However, if you're new to this, I highly suggest against that. An alternative to a backend dashboard would be something [like this](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-dashboard-page/).

If you have a site that requires members I suggest looking into using a [membership plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search.php?q=members) which would make that a whole lot easier.

Comment: Thanks Bryan, can you tell me how can I put buttons that will hyperlink to pages and posts edit. e.g. "Home" button will show-up in dashboard and if we click, it should redirect to home edit page.